# How do I clear out a flooded house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I flooded my house trying to fill a cauldron and water is pouring everywhere. What is the best way to clear out a flooded house?

Comment: Could you describe the problem further? You also could post a image. (With that low rank not but you can upload it on a other site and provide the link here). It is hard to solve the problem with that little information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you've done is merely place the water incorrectly. Rather than clicking on the cauldron itself, you have clicked on the space next to it.

If that is correct, you can salvage the situation by picking up the water source with your bucket again, or by placing a block on it.

When you fill a cauldron, you can click on the cauldron itself to fill it up.

Comment: Also, dont press shift when right clicking the cauldron might be a better idea.